# Compare vector of vectors

Tags: c++, performance, vector, comparison

I have a vector of vectors that store pointers. Currently I iterate over them and compare each pointer and if I find ones that are not equal then vectors also do not equal, but I wonder if it is the right way to do such a thing.

UPD: `std::vector<std::vector<Combination*> > combinations;`

Comment: Are you comparing the pointers themselves?  Or are you dereferencing them first?  If the former, then just use [`operator==`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/operator_cmp) on the whole vector.  Otherwise, the way you're doing it is fine.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley i compare pointers. So should i use == on vector of vectors or each vector?

Comment: @Stals, Once on the outer vector will work. It will compare each element, which will compare each pointer.

Comment: If you apply it to the vector of vectors, it will subsequently compare each subvector.  The subvectors will be compared by comparing each pointer.  The first failed pointer comparison will cause the subvector comparison to fail.  And the first failed subvector comparison will cause the whole operation to fail.  Any size mismatch, in either the size of the subvectors, or the size of the vector of vectors, will result in immediate failure.  If that's what you want, then yes, just compare the whole vector of vectors.

Comment: @Stals: it would be easier if you could show the type declaration.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley That is exactly what I do right now, but I implemented it my self, not knowing that comparison operator will do that for me. Thanks for the reply.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley Could you please copy that as an answer, so that i can accept it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're comparing the pointers themselves then you can just use [`operator==`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/operator_cmp) on the whole vector (of vectors).  What it does is first checks if the sizes of the two vectors are equal.  If they are, it subsequently compares each element using `operator==`.  So this works recursively if you have a vector of vectors, or a vector of vectors of vectors. Though it's not technically recursion, since each `operator==` is actually a different function.

If you're dereferencing the pointers, the way you're doing it is fine.  But for that case you could consider using [`std::equal`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/equal) with an appropriate predicate.